# Jquery inside of Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make some text inside of a jquery slideup slide down request but when I add another jquery code it shows this

```
â€‹
```

So here is my code

```
<head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
<!-- HIDE FROM INCOMPATIBLE BROWSERS
var fish1Position = 0;
var fish2Position = 0;
var fish3Position = 99;
var horizontal = [];
var fillPosition = 10;
var num = 100;
for(var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        horizontal[i] = fillPosition;
        fillPosition += 10;
}

function fish1Swim() {
        document.getElementById("fish1").style.left = horizontal[fish1Position] + "px";
        ++fish1Position;
        if (fish1Position == num) {
                fish1Position = 0;
}
var tim1 = setTimeout(fish1Swim, 100);
}
function fish2Swim(){
        document.getElementById("fish2").style.left = horizontal[fish2Position] + "px";
         ++fish2Position;
         if (fish2Position == num) {
                 fish2Position = 0;
}
var tim2 = setTimeout(fish2Swim, 200);
}

function fish3Swim() {
     document.getElementById("fish3").style.left = horizontal[fish3Position] + "px";
     ++fish3Position;
     if (fish3Position == num) {
fish3Position = 99;
}
var tim3 = setTimeout(fish3Swim, 300);
}

function startSwimming() {
        fish1Swim();
        fish2Swim();
        fish3Swim();
}

// STOP HIDING FROM INCOMPATIBLE BROWSERS -->
</script>
</head>
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
<body>
<ul>
<li><img src='http://station2k.com/blank-hockey-puck.png' width='17px' height='17px'> {$nhlteam} ​<span id='fish1'>{$nhlmessage}</span></li>
<li><img src='http://station2k.com/blank-hockey-puck.png' width='17px' height='17px'> {$nhlteam} ​<span id='fish1'>{$nhlmessage}</span></li>
</ul>
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
<!-- include jQuery core code -->
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  function textloop() {
    // get the item that currently has the 'show' class
    var current = $('#items .show');
    /*
     * find the next item with some help from jQuery's ternary operator
     * the syntax for the ternary operator is 'a ? b : c'
     * in other words 'if a is true return b otherwise return c'
     */
    var next = current.next().length ? current.next() : current.parent().children(':first');
    // fade out the current item and remove the 'show' class
    current.delay(5000).slideUp('slow',function(){
      // fade in the next item and add the 'show' class
      next.slideDown('slow').addClass('show');
    }).removeClass('show');

    // repeat by calling the textloop method again after 3 seconds
    setTimeout(textloop,0);
  }

  // call the text loop method when the page loads
  textloop();
});
</script>
```

Any help on making the text in the lists scroll? pref in a tag that I can id as I don't want the whole script scrolling right to left

Comment: Have you tried linking to external scripts rather than embedding

Comment: would i wrap the script tag around the span still?

Comment: I'm still getting the text

Comment: @ZacharyTylerWiggins: It's very difficult to follow the problem here.  On what specific line of code are you seeing an issue?  What are the relevant runtime values when that happens?  Can you demonstrate this in a live location such as jsfiddle or a self-hosted page somewhere?

Comment: from what I'm thinking is that me wrapping java around a php call maybe is getting this error due to character encoding. Anyway to solve this?

Comment: @ZacharyTylerWiggins: Define "wrapping java (I think you mean JavaScript) around a php call".  If there's a client-side error, please show the client-side code causing the error.  And indicate where the error is.  It's very much not clear in the code you've posted.

Comment: in the code `<li><img src='http://station2k.com/blank-hockey-puck.png' width='17px' height='17px'> {$nhlteam} ​<span id='fish1'>{$nhlmessage}</span></li>` anything after the span doesn't appear. I think the php {$nhlmessage} cannot be called inside of the java due to character encoding issues because I get {$nhlteam} fine it's just anything in that span shows â€‹.

Comment: did you try making a php element like `<?php echo $nhlteam ?>` You need to actually write the value to your html file.

Comment: so end the php sting then continue it? I'll do that

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your PHP value output to this:

```
 <li><img src='http://station2k.com/blank-hockey-puck.png' width='17px' height='17px'><?php echo $nhlteam ?>​<span id='fish1'><?php echo $nhlmessage ?></span></li>
```

The symbol you are seeing is the ASCII representation of the memory pointer to your variable.

Comment: I did that now it isn't echoing the string lol and I know there's something there in the string..... grrr I get down voted for asking a good question. Thanks for your help though!